# I have a prolem with propagation (bubbeling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some problems with bubbling. I've tried event.stopPropagation(); and some other solutions I've came across on the internet, but I cant get it to work.

I have a main div for bootstrap, with a table inside. I want the header to be clickable and open a modal, and I also want every row to be clickable and open a different modal. All the said elements are populated with jQuery.data() objects which I want to use in the modal. Even if I try event.stopPropropegation(), both the main div modal and the  modal function fires when I click a row (as expected with bubbeling). Can you please point me in the right direction as I have no clue of what I'm doing wrong, and I've tried a lot of examples now. It would be a great help. Thank you. Code:

```
 var mainbody = $('<div class="panel panel-default" id="' + tableId1 + '">\
                <div class="panel-heading">\
                    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="AppObj.removeSystem(this);">&times;</button>\
                    System: ' + name + 
              ' </div>' +
               '<table id="' + tableId2 + '"class="systems table"><thead>\
                  <tr><th> Product </th><th> DryFilm thickness min </th><th> DryFilm thickness Avg. </th><th> DryFilm thickness max </th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>\
                </table>\
             </div>');
// Here I've been trying alot of examples to stop the bubbeling
mainbody.click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
AppObj.editSystem(this);
console.log(e.target, this);
});

 // The clickable rows....
var row = $('<tr class="productrow" onclick="AppObj.editProduct(this);"><td class="productname" style="cursor: pointer;">' + showName + '</td><td class="dryfilmmin">' + dryFilmMin + '</td><td class="dryfilmavg">' + dryFilmAvg + '</td><td class="dryfilmmax">' + dryFilmMax + '</td></tr>')[0];
$.data(row, 'productinformation', {
    systemId: tableId1,
    rank: rank,
    product: i,
    dryFilmMin: dryFilmMin,
    dryFilmMax, dryFilmMax,
    dryFilmAvg: dryFilmAvg
});
mainbody.find('tbody').append(row)
```

Comment: 1. Try using delegation provided by jquery
2. `AppObj.editProduct(this)` this function should not only say `ev.stopPropagation()` but also say `return false`
3. check ev.target in case you want to differentiate betwween the object that were clicked.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir. This is worked like a charm. The delegation method was god sent, I probably need it in many other cases as I go along with this project! Do I actually need stopPropagation() when I delegate the event to a selector?

Comment: Its preferable in case you attach same event on any of the parents of the same element